# Adding messages to grib2 files

Tags: grib

**Context**

I would like to add additional fields to a `grib2` file, which are a function of existing fields.

e.g.: I would like to add a wind-chill message, given by the formula:

```
35.74 + 0.6215 * T -35.75 * V^0.16 + 0.4275 * T * V^0.16
```

- where T and V are the temperature and wind speed field that appears in the original `grib2` file.

**Question**

I have searched for documentation on the subject, but failed to find any reference :(
Is there any easy way doing that (preferably using bash, other interfaces are also relevant...)?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Multi-field messages are generally considered a bad idea. Regardless, to edit a message, you can use [grib_api](https://software.ecmwf.int/wiki/display/GRIB/Documentation) or [wgrib](http://www.cpc.ncep.noaa.gov/products/wesley/wgrib.html).